# Start multiple SparkContext Instances in Ipython

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

i have Ipython and 3.2(Jupiter) running against pyspark on rhel 6. I'm only able to launch one python2 script at a time because there is only one spark context. When I launch and run another script(kernel) in Ipython I receive an "address already in use 0.0.0.0:4040".

To be able to run multiple development efforts on the same spark+yarn cluster I believe I will need multiple SparkContext instances.

How can I achieve this parallel development effort on spark on the same Ipython notebook without having to continually shutdown a running instance ?

Comment: Good spots. So I'm somewhat confused, how do people run multiple applications on the same cluster? The lack of SparkContext instances means that I can only run things serially, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is not about using multiple Spark contexts (which is absolutely fine, it's just one Spark context per JVM or per driver).

The error says that the Spark UI port is set to 4040 and that port is already used by a running app. You should set it to different ports for each app, e.g.

```
sparkConf.set("spark.ui.port", "4050")
```

Comment: Ok understood. But I have no known ability to influence the attachment of pyspark against another JVM/SparkContext instance. How would a solution work for my Ipython parallel development process on the same notebook?

Comment: Can you set the port? Do you set up the SparkContext yourself or is IPython doing that for you?

Comment: Ipython is setting it up for me. What happens is that each script (Ipython kernel) I open to write remains in a "kernel busy" state, only the script that first ran and created the SparkContext is in a "kernel idle" state.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue.  I have configured ~/.bashrc to export PYSPRAK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook', so when I start pyspark from terminal, it launches notebook. But when in my notebook, I execute SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate(), it WARN SparkContext: Another SparkContext is being constructed .......error, since only one SparkContext should be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). The other SparkContext was created at: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)

Comment: I have also tried to set spark-defaults.conf with spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts true.  But no luck...